# Cannot get field value from shapefile

Tags: arcpy, polygon, spatial-analyst, cost-path, error-000860

In a for loop, the code tried to select one dam feature out from a set of dams and create a new shapefile so to perform cost path analysis with it. However, it seems field value of the new shapefile cannot be extracted or used to perform a cost path analysis. The shapefile was selected and created correctly and I was able to see fields when adding data to ArcMap.

Here's the code:

```
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inPtFeatures)   
for row in rows:     
  gId = row.getValue(keyAttr)

print ("Processing "+str(gId)+"...") 
elev = row.getValue(keyAttr2)

  if os.path.exists(procDir+"/"+str(gId)):
    shutil.rmtree(procDir+"/"+str(gId))

os.mkdir(procDir+"/"+str(gId))
currentDir = procDir+"/"+str(gId)
currentPtFeat = currentDir+"/pt_"+str(gId)+".shp"

whereSQL = '"GRAND_ID" = '+str(gId)
arcpy.Select_analysis(inPtFeatures,currentPtFeat,whereSQL)
print ("test2")

method = "EACH_CELL"
destField = "FID"
outCostPath = arcpy.sa.CostPath(currentPtFeat,inDem,inFdir,method,destField)
outCostPath.save(currentRastPath)
```

and error message:

```
\Functions.py", line 688, 
in CostPath     destination_field)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 47, 
in swapper     result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 681, 
in wrapper     destination_field)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 498, 
in <lambda>     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True)) 
ExecuteError: ERROR 000860: Input raster or feature destination data: is not the type of Composite Geodataset, or does not exist. ERROR 001000: Destination field: Field FID does not exist
```

Comment: The spacing in the code was all over the place, I've tried to correct it, but please check it is as expected.

Comment: sorry about spacing in the text. sth wrong with it when copying the code. I think I found the reason of the error. it looks the point location (input feature) is at boarder and that cause some issue

Comment: @Michelle Please consider adding a detailed answer to your question (based on your comment) so we can consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that you are referencing a shapefile and not a feature class. Or that the path to the shapefile is not being found.

One thing that I usually do when running a new Python script is printouts so that I can see what is being passed along in the code. I see that you are doing one print maybe add some more in at different places.

Try changing this - `currentPtFeat = currentDir+"/pt_"+str(gId)+".shp"`

To this - `currentPtFeat = currentDir+"/pt_"+str(gId)`

Or giving the full path.

As it notes in this help topic:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/34477